# cleaning address data for germany using regex

Tags: pandas, regex, string, data-cleaning, street-address

I have a got CSV with 50k rows and I have been asked to manually check the address and correct it. Unfortunately, I am short of ideas.

The address data looks like this, please see below 1 example

```
The correct address as per google is  : 
Baroper Str. 43 44892 Bochum
```

But the address stored in my CSV looks like

```
Baroperstrasse 4 3 44892  Böchum
Baroperstr. 4343 44892 böchum
Baroperstraße  43 43 44892 bochum
Baroper straße 4-3 44892 Bochum
baroperstrasse 43 44892 BöchUm
Baroper Strasse 4.3 44892 Böchüm
```

and these are just a few examples, there could be worse entries as well. Do we have a way to map them to the correct address via some google API or any other python library?

How about we use regex first to clean the basic data, for example remove the extra spaces, remove the "-" "." signs

```
messy_address['address'].str.replace('.-','', regex=True)
```

this regex doesn't help much.

my full code looks like this, the API I am using helps but I am losing house number

```
import pandas as pd
messy_address = pd.read_csv("address.csv")

messy_address['address']= messy_address['address'].str.replace('.','', regex=True)
messy_address['address']=messy_address['address'].str.replace('-','', regex=True)

# OpenStreetMap Free API
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="abcd@gmail.com")

def extract_clean_address(address):
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        return location.address
    except:
        return ''
messy_address['clean address'] = messy_address.apply(lambda x: extract_clean_address(x['address']) , axis =1  )

print(messy_address)
```

output looks like

```
clean address
Baroper Straße, Kaltehardt, Langendreer, Bochum-Ost, Bochum, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 44892, Deutschland
Baroper Straße, Kaltehardt, Langendreer, Bochum-Ost, Bochum, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 44892, Deutschland
Baroper Straße, Kaltehardt, Langendreer, Bochum-Ost, Bochum, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 44892, Deutschland
Baroper Straße, Kaltehardt, Langendreer, Bochum-Ost, Bochum, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 44892, Deutschland
Baroper Straße, Kaltehardt, Langendreer, Bochum-Ost, Bochum, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 44892, Deutschland
Baroper Straße, Kaltehardt, Langendreer, Bochum-Ost, Bochum, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 44892, Deutschland
```

Would be amazing to brainstorm here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way to handling this particular problem may be handling the CSV with pandas. Done that, you can use the Google GeoCoding API

Comment: @lucas_7_94 thanks for replying - I have updated my question,  with free API i am losing some data

Comment: if you use `regex` then dot has special meaning - it match any char - and it can makes problems. You may need to `\.` to search real dot. And you may need to use list of chars `"[\.-]"` to replace `.` or  `-`. OR you should use `regex=False`